# IE 9 displays content inconsistently

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I had an issue where ie 8 and 9 were displaying my content inconsistently.

The content was form data displayed in tables.

The content was sometimes nested in subtables.

The html was wellformed.

The content was dynamically created.

I couldn't figure out the erratic behavior for quite sometime and wanted to document the resolution in case someone else was running into this problem.

Comment: Well, that was lovely.  Oh, and you might want to add a couple images to illustrate the issue, and change the title to be more exact.  Would greatly improve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tables sometimes had cells that spanned rows and columns.
I discovered that the erratic behavior occured when a row was left incomplete as shown below in the second row.  Other browsers handled the scenario gracefully, while IE displayed the information sometimes correctly, sometimes incorrectly.

the resolution was to add blank cells so that IE would not get confused.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```